# i get "indexOf is not a function" when button clicked, why is that?

Tags: javascript

i'v created a simple html & javascript file, and i'm trying to get the element index on click, why am i getting "indexOf is not a function"?
heres the code:

```
<button id="1">1</button>
<button id="2">2</button>
<button id="3">3</button>
<button id="4">4</button>
<button id="1">5</button>

<script>

    var items = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                var ind = items.indexOf(this);
                console.log(ind);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: on which browser is this happening ? If it's on IE < 9 this is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is then one @Quentin mentioned.

To work around this, you could create a new array from the `HTMLCollection` using `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
items = Array.prototype.slice.call(items);
...
```

You can learn more about converting array-like objects to array with `.slice` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects

**ES2015 Alternative**

With ES2015, you have some more idiomatic alternatives:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
items = Array.from(items);
```

or:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
items = [...items];
```

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` is a method found on Array objects.

`getElementsByTagName` returns a live HTMLCollection, not an Array. It is Array-like in many ways (e.g. it has numerically indexed properties and a `length`) but it doesn't have all the properties of an Array.

You may be able to access the `indexOf` property of an Array (or of the prototype of the Array constructor) and use `.call()` or `.apply()` to use it in the context of the HTMLCollection object.

Answer (score 0):

[`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), not an array. HTMLCollections doesn't have the `indexOf` method, which is why you're getting this error.

You can convert the list to an array, which will mean you can use `indexOf`.

```
var items = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do by closure function to get element index!!

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
(function (a){
               items[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
               var ind = items[a];
               console.log(ind);
            });
})(i);
}
```